How do I return results from an external function to use in R shiny?
I am building a fairly complicated R shiny app where the user makes several selections and also uploads a file. All this information is intended to be sent to several functions for processing. The results of the first function ('lifehistory.sims') will be used to create several graphs and as input into another function, which I have not yet added to the code as I am stuck on returning and using result from the first function. The app code is as follows:
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)


##########################################################################################################
##  PREP  ################################################################################################
###########################################################################################################---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#-CLEAN R CONSOLE-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))   #==>Clears the names of any objects


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#-SET WORKING DIRECTORY-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
setwd("C:/Users/lmlee/OneDrive - DOI/Documents/R work/shiny/lmtest")


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#-SOURCE EXTERNAL FUNCTIONS-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
source("./utils.R",local=TRUE)


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#-READ IN DATA--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
lw.cisco <- read_excel("cisco.xlsx",sheet="lenwt")

agelen.cisco <- read_excel("cisco.xlsx",sheet="agelen")

mat.cisco <- read_excel("cisco.xlsx",sheet="maturity")

fwt.cisco <- read_excel("cisco.xlsx",sheet="fecundweight")

flen.cisco <- read_excel("cisco.xlsx",sheet="fecundlength")


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#-MISCELLANEOUS-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
stat.dist <- c("Fix","Uniform","Normal","Triangle")


##########################################################################################################
##  SHINY  ###############################################################################################
##########################################################################################################
ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "blue",
  dashboardHeader(title = "Lake Erie Cisco PVA - Leslie Matrix Model",titleWidth = 450),
  dashboardSidebar(id="",
             width = 450,
             sidebarMenu(
                    menuItem("Welcome",tabName = "menuWelcome", icon = shiny::icon("face-smile")),
                menuItem("Model Set Up",tabName = "menuSetup", icon = shiny::icon("wrench"),startExpanded = TRUE,
                        menuSubItem("Dimensions",tabName = "menuDim", icon = shiny::icon("list-ol")),
                        menuSubItem("Proposed Stocking",tabName = "menuStocking", icon = shiny::icon("fish")),
                        menuSubItem("Growth Parameters",tabName = "menuGrowth", icon = shiny::icon("arrow-up-right-dots")),
                        menuSubItem("Maturity",tabName = "menuMaturity", icon = shiny::icon("hourglass-half")),
                        menuSubItem("Fecundity",tabName = "menuFecundity", icon = shiny::icon("egg")),
                        menuSubItem("Allee Effect",tabName = "menuAllee", icon = shiny::icon("xmarks-lines")),
                        menuSubItem("Threats",tabName = "menuThreats", icon = shiny::icon("triangle-exclamation"))),
                menuItem("Run Model",tabName = "menuRun", icon = shiny::icon("person-running")),
                menuItemOutput("menuResults"),
                menuItem("Additional Info",tabName = "menuInfo", icon = shiny::icon("info")))),
  dashboardBody(

    useShinyjs(),

      tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML("
      .box {
        overflow: scroll;
      }"))
      ),
            
            tabItems(
            ##################################################
            ##  MENU: WELCOME  ###############################
            ##################################################
            tabItem(tabName = "menuWelcome",valueBox("Population Viability Analysis","Welcome",icon = shiny::icon("face-smile"),width=8)),


            ##################################################
            ##  MENU: DIMENSIONS  ############################
            ##################################################
            tabItem(tabName = "menuDim",fluidRow(valueBox("Dimensions","Set",icon = shiny::icon("list-ol"),width=8)),
                                fluidRow(box(sliderInput("n.projections","Number projection years",value=100,min=0,max=200,step=5),width=8)),
                                fluidRow(box(sliderInput("n.simulations","Number simulations",value=5000,min=0,max=10000,step=100),width=8)),
                                fluidRow(box(numericInput("age.max","Maximum age",value=15,min=1,max=30),width=4))),


            ##################################################
            ##  MENU: PROPOSED STOCKING ######################
            ##################################################
            tabItem(tabName = "menuStocking",
                            fluidRow(valueBox("Proposed Stocking","Load Data",icon = shiny::icon("fish"),width=8)),
                            fluidRow(box(title="Data Load",status="primary",solidHeader=TRUE,fileInput('file1', 'Choose xlsx file',accept = c(".xlsx")),width=8)),
                            fluidRow(box(title="Loaded Data",status="primary",solidHeader=TRUE,tableOutput('in.df.stocking'),width=8,height=400))),


            ##################################################
            ##  MENU: GROWTH PARAMETERS  #####################
            ##################################################
            tabItem(tabName = "menuGrowth",
                            fluidRow(valueBox("Growth Parameters","Select",icon = shiny::icon("arrow-up-right-dots"),width=8)),
                            fluidRow(column(6,style="width:25%;",
                                            box(title="von Bertalanffy Age-Length Parameters",status="primary",solidHeader=TRUE,
                                            radioButtons("vB.dist","Select distribution or fix",stat.dist),width=NULL)),
                                   column(6,style="width:41.6%;",
                                            box(title="Age-Length Graph",status="primary",solidHeader=TRUE,plotOutput("p.agelen"),width=NULL))),
                            fluidRow(column(6,style="width:25%;",
                                            box(title="Length-Weight Parameters",status="primary",solidHeader=TRUE,
                                            radioButtons("lw.dist","Select distribution or fix",stat.dist),width=NULL)),
                                   column(6,style="width:41.6%;",
                                            box(title="Length-Weight Graph",status="primary",solidHeader=TRUE,plotOutput("p.lenwt"),width=NULL)))),


            ##################################################
            ##  MENU: MATURITY  ##############################
            ##################################################
            tabItem(tabName = "menuMaturity",
                        fluidRow(valueBox("Maturity","proportion mature",icon = shiny::icon("hourglass-half"),width=8)),
                        fluidRow(box(title="Maturity Graph",status="primary",solidHeader=TRUE,plotOutput("p.maturity"),width=8))
            ),


            ##################################################
            ##  MENU: FECUNDITY  #############################
            ##################################################
            tabItem(tabName = "menuFecundity",
                        fluidRow(valueBox("Fecundity","eggs",icon = shiny::icon("egg"),width=8)),   
                        fluidRow(box(title="Fecundity-Weight Graph",status="primary",solidHeader=TRUE,plotOutput("p.fecundwt"),width=8)),
                        fluidRow(box(title="Fecundity-Length Graph",status="primary",solidHeader=TRUE,plotOutput("p.fecundlen"),width=8))

            ),


            ##################################################
            ##  MENU: ALLEE EFFECT  ##########################
            ##################################################
            tabItem(tabName = "menuAllee",
                        fluidRow(valueBox("Allee Effect","define threshold",icon = shiny::icon("xmarks-lines"),width=8))
            ),


            ##################################################
            ## MENU: THREATS  ################################
            ##################################################
            tabItem(tabName = "menuThreats",
                        fluidRow(valueBox("Threats","threats",icon = shiny::icon("triangle-exclamation"),width=8))

            ),


            ##################################################
            ## MENU: RUN MODEL  ##############################
            ##################################################
            tabItem(tabName = "menuRun",
                            fluidRow(valueBox("Run Model","Review and run",icon = shiny::icon("person-running"),width=8)),
                            fluidRow(box(title="Review Inputs",status="primary",solidHeader=TRUE,tableOutput('review.input'),width=8),
                                            actionButton("btnRunModel","Run Model",icon = shiny::icon("person-running"),class="btn-lg btn-primary")),
                            fluidRow(box(title="Review Proposed Stocking",status="primary",solidHeader=TRUE,tableOutput('review.df.stocking'),width=8,height=400))),


            ##################################################
            ## MENU: RESULTS  ################################
            ##################################################
            tabItem(tabName = "menuResults",
                            fluidRow(valueBox("Results","Output",icon = shiny::icon("magnifying-glass-chart"),width=8)),
                            fluidRow(box(title="Model Summary",status="primary",solidHeader=TRUE,textOutput("out.summary"),width=8)),
                            fluidRow(
                                tabBox(width = 8,
                                    tabPanel("Growth",
                                        fluidRow(box(title="Linf Graph",status="primary",solidHeader=TRUE,plotOutput("p.Linf"),width=8)),
                                        fluidRow(box(title="stats",width=8))

                            ) #growth
                                    
                            ))
                            ),


            ##################################################
            ## MENU: ADDITIONAL INFO##########################
            ##################################################
            tabItem(tabName = "menuInfo",fluidRow(valueBox("Additional Info","Check here for latest update information",icon = shiny::icon("info"),width=7)),
                            fluidRow("Last update: October 2024"),
                            fluidRow("Issue tracking: laura_lee@fws.gov"))

  
  ))
)


##########################################################################################################

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  ##################################################
  ##  REVIEW INPUT #################################
  ##################################################
  output$review.input <- renderTable({
    df.input <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=1, nrow=5))
       colnames(df.input) <- c("Value")
    rownames(df.input) <- c("N projections","N simulations","Max age","von B age-length","length-weight")
    df.input[1,1] <- input$n.projections
    df.input[2,1] <- input$n.simulations
    df.input[3,1] <- input$age.max
    df.input[4,1] <- input$vB.dist
    df.input[5,1] <- input$lw.dist
      return(df.input)
  },rownames = TRUE)
  ##################################################


  ##################################################
  ##  INPUT PROPOSED STOCKING  #####################
  ##################################################
  data1 <- reactive({
    req(input$file1)
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)){return(NULL)}

    isolate({ 
        df.stocking <- read_excel(inFile$datapath, sheet ="stocking")
    })
    df.stocking
  })
  output$in.df.stocking <- renderTable({data1()},rownames=FALSE,digits=0)  
  output$review.df.stocking <- renderTable({data1()},rownames=FALSE,digits=0)
  ##################################################


  ##################################################
  ##  PLOT AGE-LENGTH  #############################
  ##################################################
  output$p.agelen <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = agelen.cisco, aes(x=age, y = length)) +
        geom_line(color="blue",linewidth=1.25) +
        labs(x="Age",
                 y="Length (mm)") +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
            axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
            axis.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12),
            plot.title = element_text(face = "bold",size = 12, hjust= 0.5),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color="grey"),
            axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
  })
  ##################################################


  ##################################################
  ##  PLOT LENGTH-WEIGHT  ##########################
  ##################################################
  output$p.lenwt <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = lw.cisco, aes(x=length, y = weight)) +
        geom_line(color="blue",linewidth=1.25) +
        labs(x="Length (cm)",
                 y="Weight (g)") +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
            axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
            axis.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12),
            plot.title = element_text(face = "bold",size = 12, hjust= 0.5),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color="grey"),
            axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
  })
  ##################################################


  ##################################################
  ##  PLOT MATURITY  ###############################
  ##################################################
  output$p.maturity <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = mat.cisco, aes(x=age, y = maturity)) +
        geom_line(color="blue",linewidth=1.25) +
        labs(x="Age",
                 y="Proportion Mature") +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
            axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
            axis.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12),
            plot.title = element_text(face = "bold",size = 12, hjust= 0.5),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color="grey"),
            axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
  })
  ##################################################


  ##################################################
  ##  PLOT FECUNDITY-WEIGHT  #######################
  ##################################################
  output$p.fecundwt <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = fwt.cisco, aes(x=weight, y=fecundity, group=water)) +
        geom_line(linewidth=1.25,aes(color=water)) +
        labs(x="Weight (g)",
                 y="Number of Eggs") + 
        scale_color_manual(values=c("green3","darkblue")) +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
            axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
            axis.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12),
            plot.title = element_text(face = "bold",size = 12, hjust= 0.5),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color="grey"),
            axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))

  })
  ##################################################


  ##################################################
  ##  PLOT FECUNDITY-LENGTH  #######################
  ##################################################
  output$p.fecundlen <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = flen.cisco, aes(x=length, y=fecundity, group=water)) +
        geom_line(linewidth=1.25,aes(color=water)) +
        labs(x="Length (mm)",
                 y="Number of Eggs") + 
        scale_color_manual(values=c("darkgreen","mediumpurple3")) +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
            axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
            axis.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12),
            plot.title = element_text(face = "bold",size = 12, hjust= 0.5),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color="grey"),
            axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))

  })
  ##################################################


  ##################################################
  ##  RUN MODEL  ###################################
  ##################################################
  run_pva <- eventReactive(input$btnRunModel, {

    n.projections <- input$n.projections
        n.simulations <- input$n.simulations
    age.max <- input$age.max
    age <- 1:age.max
    vonB.est <- input$vB.dist
        lw.est <- input$lw.dist
        stocking.dat <- input$df.stocking
    stocking.pro <- as.data.frame(stocking.dat)
    stocking.pro <- subset(stocking.pro, select = -c(stocking.pro$Month))
    month.stock <- as.numeric(unlist(stocking.dat[,2]))
    n.stockpro <- ncol(stocking.pro) - 1

    Linf.mean <- 358.96         #==>in mm; used for fixed and normal; used as mode in triangular
    Linf.sd <- 2.5956           #==>in mm; used for normal
    Linf.min <- 353.869         #==>in mm; used for triangular and uniform
    Linf.max <- 364.051         #==>in mm: used for triangular and uniform

    K.mean <- 0.63728           #==>used for fixed and normal; used as mode in triangular
    K.sd <- 0.05272         #==>used for normal
    K.min <- 0.5338674          #==>used for triangular and uniform
    K.max <- 0.7406828          #==>used for triangular and uniform

    t0.mean <- -0.65887         #==>used for fixed and normal; used as mode in triangular
    t0.sd <- 0.16103            #==>used for normal
    t0.min <- -0.9747422        #==>used for triangular and uniform
    t0.max <- -0.3429936        #==>used for triangular and uniform

    lw.a.mean <- 0.000002300623 #==>in mm and g; used for fixed and normal; used as mode in triangular
    lw.a.sd <-  0.0000003716823 #==>in mm and g; used for (truncated) normal
    lw.a.min <- 0.000001664513      #==>in mm and g; used for triangular and uniform
    lw.a.max <- 0.000003113637      #==>in mm and g; used for triangular and uniform

    lw.b.mean <- 3.242949       #==>used for fixed and normal; used as mode in triangular
    lw.b.sd <- 0.02704049       #==>used for normal
    lw.b.min <- 3.192604        #==>used for triangular and uniform
    lw.b.max <- 3.296984        #==>used for triangular and uniform

    n.fecund <- 4
    fecund <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=2,nrow=n.fecund))
    colnames(fecund) <- c("a","b")
    fecund[1,1] <- -86.5        #==>a for fecundity-weight; weight in g; Wisconsin
    fecund[1,2] <- 46.5         #==>b for fecundity-weight; weight in g; Wisconsin
    fecund[2,1] <- -440.35      #==>a for fecundity-weight; weight in g; Ontario
    fecund[2,2] <- 44.48        #==>b for fecundity-weight; weight in g; Ontario
    fecund[3,1] <- 2.919        #==>a for fecundity-length; total length in cm; Superior
    fecund[3,2] <- 0.037        #==>b for fecundity-length; total length in cm; Superior
    fecund[4,1] <- 2.978        #==>a for fecundity-length; total length in cm; Michigan/Huron
    fecund[4,2] <- 0.037        #==>b for fecundity-length; total length in cm; Michigan/Huron

    eggS <- 0.00217625


    b <- lifehistory.sims(n.simulations,age,vonB.est,Linf.mean,Linf.sd,Linf.min,Linf.max,
                K.mean,K.sd,K.min,K.max,t0.mean,t0.sd,t0.min,t0.max,
                lw.est,lw.a.mean,lw.a.sd,lw.a.min,lw.a.max,
                lw.b.mean,lw.b.sd,lw.b.min,lw.b.max,
                fecund,n.fecund,eggS)
 
  })
  ##################################################


  ##################################################
  ##  MODEL SUMMARY TEXT  ##########################
  ##################################################
  output$out.summary <- renderText({
    paste("The model ran")
  })
  ##################################################


  ##################################################
  ##  SHOW RESULTS MENU ############################
  ##################################################
  output$menuResults <- renderMenu({
    if(input$btnRunModel > 0)
      menuItem("Results", tabName = "menuResults", icon = icon("magnifying-glass-chart")
      )
  })
  ##################################################


  ##################################################
  ##  PLOT LINF  ###################################
  ##################################################
  output$p.Linf <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = as.data.frame(b$sim.bio), aes(x=sim.bio$Linf)) + 
        geom_histogram(color="lightskyblue4", fill="lightskyblue2") +
        labs(title="Linf",
            x="Linf (mm)",
            y="frequency") +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 8),
            axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8),
            axis.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12),
            plot.title = element_text(face = "bold",size = 12, hjust= 0.5),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color="grey"),
            axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
  })
  ##################################################



session$onSessionEnded(stopApp)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)

The 'lifehistory.sims' function is in utils.R and returns a list containing several data frames.
I was directed to Returning a dataframe in a reactive function in R Shiny Dashboard but the function referenced in that articles binds the data into a single data frame where as my function is returning multiple data frames. I am having trouble figuring out how to reference the results of the function in the creation of the graph (p.Linf).
I would appreciate any help in figuring out how to return and use the results of the 'lifehistory.sims' function.

It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including a minimal and runnable example code which focuses on the issue. As is your code is neither minimal nor reproducible. This said: Asb <- lifehistory.sims(...) is the last command in your eventReactive the result is already stored in run_pva and you access the values using run_pva().

Without running your code, I guess the issue is, that the result set b (btw. bad name to search for in code) is defined only in the scope of your eventReactive "run_pva". To access the results of the eventReactive in other reactive contexts like renderPlot you'll have to use run_pva()$sim.bio instead of b$sim.bio, as b is what is returned for run_pva (similar to "normal" functions).
